# Github webhook with a server redirect

Tags: git, .htaccess, redirect, webhooks

I've got a staging server setup that has a redirect for anyone that isn't specified in by a Rewrite conditions. I'm trying to trigger a git pull once my repo is updated but the webhook keeps getting redirected because of this condition I have setup.

I've added GitHubs IP addresses to my conditions list but the webhook is still getting redirected. Is there anything else I've missed?

This is what I'm using for to redirect users.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^192.30.252.0/22
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^185.199.108.0/22
RewriteRule .* https://www.fakeaddress.com [R=302,L]
```